# Apache ActiveMQ on Centos7 Access issues

Tags: open-source

We have an Apache ActiveMQ running on Centos7 on EC2 and we are getting an Error below:

- When we use admin account to hit the endpoint on 61616 from postman we just get this error:

1.****your text****2023-11-02 13:20:07,682 | WARN | Security Error occurred on connection to: tcp://192.16.10.10:58304, User name [admin] or password is invalid. | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Service | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///192.16.10.10:58304@61616

1. 2023-11-02 13:34:59,596 | WARN | Security Error occurred on connection to: tcp://192.16.10.10:58643, User queue_sender is not authorized to read from: queue://Process_QueueT | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Service | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///192.16.10.10:58643@61616

is there some setting that needs to be changed on activemq.xml at /opt/apache-activemq-5.14.3/conf/activemq.xml ?

Activemq.xml:

" write="senders,admins" read="receivers,admins" admin="admins,senders,receivers" /> " write="senders,admins" read="receivers,senders,admins" admin="admins,senders,receivers" />

Please share your thoughts or a fix here.
Thanks.

This works fine on windows server but not linux. The site load on the browser Juts when we hit from postman we see this error.